# Substituting sugar with a liquid stevia concentrate in a cake

Tags: substitutions, cake, sugar

I have a cake recipe that consists of a dry part, a liquid oil part and eggs. Around half of the dry part consists of sugar. I would like to replace that sugar with liquid stevia concentrate at a very small fraction of the original sugar. If I do that though, then around half of the dry ingredients would be removed from the recipe.

How would I adjust such a recipe? Would I reduce the eggs and liquid oil part proportionally to how much of the dry part has been removed? Anything else that I would need to take into consideration? For example, since the sugar is not soluble in the liquid part, I'm thinking it must also bring certain physical properties to the cake.

---

I noticed that if I replace the sugar with an erythritol / xylitol blend, then the end result is very similar to the sugar product, so maybe there's a similar bulking agent I could use instead of the sugar? Polyols add sweetness as well, so they wouldn't work in conjunction with the stevia concentrate, it would ideally have to be something neutral.

Comment: what is the "concentrate" you are talking about ?

Comment: @Max, it's liquid stevia concentrate, but it would be used in extremely small quantities (a few drops in a kilogram of batter), so it will likely not contribute anything to the physical properties of the cake.

Comment: Does the recipes call for water?  If so this can help the calculation.

Comment: @Alchimista, no, there's no water in the recipe.

Comment: Ok but I see that your concentrate is so concentrated that it does not add water in fact....So here the problem is to take away a good psrt  of the solid mass. ... is at least flour the rest of the dry solid? If so try to skip sugar . Eggs and flour should bound and render a cake. You cannot really solve this without a bit of experimenting. :)

Comment: @Alchimista, yes, the rest of the dry solid is flour. That is indeed the problem - if I remove the sugar, what do I replace it with? I'm not sure if I can just remove it completely, since it's such a big part of the cake. I'll likely have to perform a series of experiments (for now I'm thinking of trying: nothing, more flour, apple sauce, a small amount of chia flour + some neutral, non-absorbent filler (maybe inulin and bamboo fiber), since chia is very absorbent and binding, which I don't really want).

Comment: Aren't you pretty much depriving your batter of one of the substances for the [Maillard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction) and other reactions that lead to characteristic flavors from sugar? I've halved the amount of sugar in an NY Cheesecake recipe from a book without much trouble (I got there with multiple tests/iterations), but I'd never remove sugar completely. Besides flour and sugar are both carbohydrates and have a similar calorie density.

Answer (score 2):

**Use dextrin.**

On the theory that dextrin (insoluble fiber) is molecularly similar to sucrose, I made chocolate chip cookies and substituted dextrin 1:1 for all the sugar, sweetening the dough with erythritol (and regular chocolate chips).  I used the CVS brand dextrin which is sold with fiber supplements like Metamucil.  A brand name for dextrin is Benefiber.  It is very much a bulking agent exactly as you request.  It has no flavor.

The dough was the right consistency and the end product was more the consistency of shortbread than a toll house cookie, but they were good.  No GI issues either.

Answer (score 1):

(depending on the cake)

You can fill in the loss of "sugar" bulk with apple sauce, apple juice, egg whites, plain unsweetened yogurt.

From what I can see on the internets, most of the time, recipes use apple sauce.

I suggest looking/searching for a stevia cake recipe on the webs to get the proper replacement ratios.

Comment: Wouldn't all of these options significantly alter the taste of the cake though?

Comment: it depends on the cake (and frosting) Me think you can't have it both ways, substitution will always have side effects, change taste, change texture...